# How to convert double to nullable int, int to nullable int in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I had to fight with this for a while. I was using AutoMapper to map between different numeric formats and constantly getting errors when mapping int to int? etc. Now, I could have modified my DTO objects to match accordingly, but it wasn't so easy.

I understand this is primarily due to boxed types and nothing to do with AutoMapper, but would be nice to see more support for type conversion (such as a flag to force implicit conversions, after all AutoMapper is a helper library).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we are going to use a custom type mapper:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
{
    // Here we're going to use some custom type converters
    // The custom converter just forces a cast between two somewhat castable types using implicit conversion.
    cfg.CreateMap<int, int?>().ConvertUsing<CastableTypeConverter<int, int?>>();
    cfg.CreateMap<double, int?>().ConvertUsing<CastableTypeConverter<double, int?>>();
    cfg.CreateMap<short, int?>().ConvertUsing<CastableTypeConverter<short, int?>>();
    cfg.CreateMap<byte, int?>().ConvertUsing<CastableTypeConverter<byte, int?>>();
    cfg.CreateMap<double, int>().ConvertUsing<CastableTypeConverter<double, int>>();
    cfg.CreateMap<decimal, int>().ConvertUsing<CastableTypeConverter<decimal, int>>();
    cfg.CreateMap<decimal, double>().ConvertUsing<CastableTypeConverter<decimal, double>>();
    cfg.CreateMap<short, int>().ConvertUsing<CastableTypeConverter<short, int>>();
    cfg.CreateMap<byte, int>().ConvertUsing<CastableTypeConverter<byte, int>>();
    /*...*/
});


/// <summary>
/// This just forces implicit casting between two types (that are castable!)
/// Such as (int) to (int?), or (double) to (int)
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TSrc"></typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TDst"></typeparam>
private class CastableTypeConverter<TSrc, TDst> : TypeConverter<TSrc, TDst>
{
    protected override TDst ConvertCore(TSrc source)
    {
        Type srcType = typeof(TSrc);
        Type destType = typeof(TDst);
        TDst result = Activator.CreateInstance<TDst>();
        // a syntactical optimization
        object src = source;
        object dst = source;
        if (destType.IsGenericType && destType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Nullable<>))
        {
            // get the underlying type
            destType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(destType);
        }

        // trying to cast to nullable type from non-nullable type,
        // or an implicit cast is required.
        if (destType == typeof(int) && srcType == typeof(decimal))
            dst = (int)(decimal)src;
        if (destType == typeof(int) && srcType == typeof(double))
            dst = (int)(double)src;
        if (destType == typeof(int) && srcType == typeof(float))
            dst = (int)(float)src;
        if (destType == typeof(int) && srcType == typeof(short))
            dst = (int)(short)src;
        if (destType == typeof(int) && srcType == typeof(byte))
            dst = (int)(byte)src;
        if (destType == typeof(int) && srcType == typeof(int))
            dst = (int)src;



        // now try to cast it appropriately
        try
        {
            result = (TDst)dst;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

You'll see that I'm doing a double implicit cast - the first to unbox the type and the second to the destination type. If the destination type is nullable, it won't blow up because it is already cast to the base type. And finally, if there isn't a custom conversion specified, it will try to implicitly cast and possibly blow up (intended!)

Granted - I'm not saying you should go ahead and do this for all your data types. But I'm not going to tell you how to code, just how to solve this particular problem. The proper answer here would be to match your DTO objects data types, just sayin'